# Como limitar o resultado de uma query em 2 casas decimais?

Tags: postgresql

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT  SUM(ValorBruto)
FROM faturas
WHERE DataCaptura between'2018-10-01' and '2018-10-30'
```

O resultado é exibido com 4 casas decimais. Gastaria de visualizar somente 2. Como faço?

Comment: Não deu certo :( Incorrect syntax near 'SUM'

Comment: Utilize a função to_char para formatar a exibição da maneira desejada.

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo assim

```
SELECT round(CAST(float8 SUM(ValorBruto) as valorBruto),2)
FROM faturas
WHERE DataCaptura between'2018-10-01' and '2018-10-30'
```